# Fill a vector with random numbers c++

Tags: c++, random, vector, srand

I've got a vector that I'm trying to fill up with random numbers. I keep running into an issue however that the vector mostly outputs 0 each time that I'm running it (it shouldn't output a 0 ever). What am I doing wrong in my code written below to make it output 0 (it outputs 0 more so than any other number):

```
vector<int> myVector;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
int a = rand() % 20 + 1; //1 to 20    
for (int i =0; i < a; i++){
        int b = rand() % 20 + 1;
        myVector.push_back(b);
        cout << myVector[b] << endl;
    }
```

I am a beginner and have not done much C++ programming in a long time so I'm not sure what is making my code malfunction. If someone could explain what I've done wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: myVector[b] should be myVector[i]

Comment: Or, arguably, it should be `myVector.back()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling the wrong index in your vector

Try doing:

```
cout << myVector[i] << endl;
```

else you will risk running off the end of your vertex for the first 20 or so iterations.

You can also call [.back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) on your vector to get the last item in the vector.

Comment: Ah, I figured it would be something small that I didn't see. In terms of speed would there be any difference between using .back() or [i]?

Comment: You would have to benchmark it but I strongly suspect `.back()` is faster and safer.

Comment: @Valrok btw, in the future if you have a C++11 implementation at your disposal I strongly suggest using the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library. It really solves a *lot* of issues such as modulo-bias. [See it live](http://ideone.com/T0sOhp)

Comment: @Valrok: If you turn on optimalizations, they'll probably be equally fast. The optimizer should be able to generate functionally identical code.

Answer (score 95):

You can use std::generate algorithm to fill a vector of n elements with random numbers.

In modern C++ it’s recommended not to use any time-based seeds and std::rand, but instead to use random_device to generate a seed. For software-based engine, you always need to specify the engine and distribution.   [Read More..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Extensible_random_number_facility)

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // First create an instance of an engine.
    random_device rnd_device;
    // Specify the engine and distribution.
    mt19937 mersenne_engine {rnd_device()};  // Generates random integers
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist {1, 52};
    
    auto gen = [&dist, &mersenne_engine](){
                   return dist(mersenne_engine);
               };

    vector<int> vec(10);
    generate(begin(vec), end(vec), gen);
    
    // Optional
    for (auto i : vec) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    

}
```

If you want to rearrange the elements of a range in a random order:

```
  std::shuffle(begin(vec), end(vec), mersenne_engine);
```

Comment: You should bind a reference to the `mersenne_engine` using `std::ref`, otherwise generating multiple vectors with the same generator will cause all vectors to be the same. [See the associated question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48259773/694509)

Comment: Another note of warning, `random_device` may not be very random at all! GCC under Windows for example always produces the same output for your posted code.

Answer (score 48):

What about simply:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

std::srand(unsigned(std::time(nullptr)));
std::vector<int> v(1000);
std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::rand);
```

Comment: looks like it will fill it with the same values

Comment: @x4444: On my machine it works after several tests. Maybe put a "std::srand(unsigned(std::time(nullptr)));" in front.

Answer (score 14):

Just adding my 2 cents... This response is similar to the one given by [Marko Tunjic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143753/1032917), but it doesn't use `std::rand` from C, but C++11 features instead.
It allows you to use the distribution of your choice, `uniform_int_distribution` in the example below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

static std::vector<int> generate_data(size_t size)
{
    using value_type = int;
    // We use static in order to instantiate the random engine
    // and the distribution once only.
    // It may provoke some thread-safety issues.
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<value_type> distribution(
        std::numeric_limits<value_type>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<value_type>::max());
    static std::default_random_engine generator;

    std::vector<value_type> data(size);
    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), []() { return distribution(generator); });
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::vector<int> myVector = generate_data(10);
        myVector = generate_data(10);

        std::cout << "myVector (iteration " << i << "): ";
        for (auto v: myVector)
        {
            std::cout << v << ",";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You say Marko Tunjic's answer uses `std::rand` in C? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: It used to use `rand` when I wrote my answer. Have a look at the first revision https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23143753/1.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the wrong index in your vector

```
cout << myVector[i] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are trying to do with the loop, the code is creating a vector of random size, filled with random numbers.

You are outputting "myVector[b]", but 'b' is the random value, not the index of just added number. You could just :

```
cout << b << endl;
```

But really you should size the vector, and just access by index.

```
int vec_size = rand() % 20 + 1;
vec<int> myvec(vec_size);
for( int i = 0; i < vec_size; ++i ) {
    vec[i] = rand() % 20 + 1;
}

/* output the list after you made it */
std::copy(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: The variable above it (a) is intentionally being a random number between 1 and 20, and I'm trying to make the vector be of size a with each index having a random number that is <= a

Answer (score -1):

```
cout << myVector[b] ?!
```

it should be : `cout << myVector[i];`

Answer (score -2):

```
// here I generate a vector that contains random vectors
// for example, after this code, vec = { {1,4,8}, {1,3,6,7,9}, {2,5,6} }

#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

void generate_random_vectors(const int num_of_rand_vectors, vector<vector<int>> &vec) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num_of_rand_vectors; ++j) {
        // the vector size will be randomal: between 0 to 19
        int vec_size = (rand() % 20);
        vector<int> rand_vec(vec_size);
        for (int k = 0; k < vec_size; ++k) {
            // each vec element will be randomal: between 1 to 20
            rand_vec[k] = 1 + (rand() % 20);
        }
        // each vector will be sorted if you want to
        sort(rand_vec.begin(), rand_vec.end());
        // push each of the 'num_of_rand_vectors'-th vectors into vec
        vec.push_back(rand_vec);
    }
}

void main() {

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    // input vector containing random sorted vectors
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    generate_random_vectors(3, vec);
}
```

Comment: Hardly related to the original post at all.