# suggested way to initialize/resize a container with arbitrary values

Tags: c++, function, initialization, containers

Currently I'm initializing a `list`/`vector` etc. like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec_rand(target_size);
std::generate(vec_rand.begin(), vec_rand.end(), std::rand);
```

.. as already shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516575/fill-a-vector-with-random-numbers-c). `std::rand` is just an example - it could be any function.

I was just wondering if there's a way to create/resize a container and initialize it's values with arbitrary values **at the same time**.

I know I don't have to expect a big performance boost but It would be nicer (and less verbose) to have s.th. like

```
vector<int> my_list(10, std::rand);
```

or

```
my_list.resize(target_size, std::rand);
```

rather than to first `resize()` with default values and than overwrite them with the desired content.

Comment: `vector::reserve()` followed by `std::generate_n` with a `back_inserter` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter seems reasonable. Make it an answer if you please. Close to the *same time* OP asked.

Comment: +1 because it would solve the issue with unnecessary initialization. But it's not an answer yet because you are still verbose (even more).

Comment: @frans I don't think the standard allows for this in the constructor. Get yourself appointed to the standards committee and do something about it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible in the constructor (or in a single instruction).

You can use `vector::reserve()` to allocate the memory (without initialising), and then `std::generate_n` with a `back_inserter` to fill the array.

```
my_list.reserve(target_size);
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(my_list), target_size, std::rand);
```

Comment: Maybe you could add the hint that there's no way to do this with one instruction - this would answer my question completely.

Comment: @frans As you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard vector [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) function exists in two overloaded versions (since C++11), one taking simply the new size, and one taking the new size and a default value.

So it is not directly possible using only the `resize` function, buy if you wanted to make the code less verbose, you could create a wrapper function that did it. As you said yourself, it would not be the biggest performance boost anyway.

You could perhaps even make your own type, that was initialised with a value created by your randomise function, and castable to an `int`.

Edit: Jonathan Potter's comment could be an acceptable possibility.