# Why does using std::generate to fill a vector with random data always produce the same content?

Tags: c++11, random

I am trying to fill a `std::vector` with random data using the following code ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23143753/694509)):

```
std::mt19937 mersenne_engine(time(NULL));
std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distribution(1, 10);
auto generator = std::bind(distribution, mersenne_engine);

for(unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    std::vector<unsigned int> weights(10);

    // This line always generates the same vector content.
    std::generate(weights.begin(), weights.end(), generator);
    // This line properly randomizes the content each iteration.
    //for(auto &weight : weights) weight = generator();

    for(auto &weight : weights) {
        std::cout << weight << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/t9lpPz)

For some reason this generates the same vector contents for each of the 10 iterations. Generating the weights manually (commented out line) works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `std::bind` makes a copy of `distribution` and `mersenne_engine`; and then `std::generate` makes a copy of generator. Try using `std::ref` to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Mankarse Nice catch, that was in fact the problem. Do you want to make an answer of it?

Comment: @WernerHenze Yup, I found that same question once I knew what the problem was :)