# Return Type Resolver and ambiguous overload for 'operator='

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, vector, stl

I've copied code from [this wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Return_Type_Resolver) and it works.

The problem occurs when I make this code:

```cpp
int main()
{
  std::set<int> random_s = getRandomN(10);
  std::vector<int> random_v;
  random_v = getRandomN(10);
  std::list<int> random_l = getRandomN(10);
}
```

My compiler (gcc trunk) prints out this error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' and 'getRandomN')
   43 |   random_v = getRandomN(10);
```

I don't understand why the C++ compiler can't simply take `copy operator=` but try to match `operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)` and `operator=(vector&& __x)` instead.

Here is my solution to this problem, which I don't like, but I can't think of anything else:

1. The functional cast:

   ```cpp
   random_v = std::vector<int>(getRandomN(10));
   ```

   Clearly, the type must be repeated twice.
2. Private inheritance and forwarding required methods from the parent:

   ```cpp
   template<typename T>
   class my_vector : private std::vector<T>
   {
   public:
       using std::vector<T>::end;
       using std::vector<T>::insert;

       my_vector<int>& operator=(my_vector<int> rhs) noexcept
       {
           std::swap(*this, rhs);
           return *this;
       }
   };

   my_vector<int> random_v1;
   random_v1 = getRandomN(10);
   ```

   Clearly, I don't use `std::vector<int>` anymore...

The whole code: [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Te474cnrx)

Comment: As an aside, ideally you shouldn't use rand() in production code.  I presume you're using it here for the sake of demo?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665818/generate-random-numbers-using-c11-random-library

Comment: You might want to use some functional methods such as `std::generate` too - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516575/fill-a-vector-with-random-numbers-c

Comment: Well, neither of the  the conversion sequences from `getRandomN` to `std::vector<int> const&` and or to `std::initializer_list<int>` is better... Making `getRandomN` a template function wouldn't make the code much more verbose though: `auto random_v = getRandomN<std::vector<int>>(10); auto random_l = getRandomN<std::list<int>>(10);`

Comment: @fabian don't you mean `std::vector<int>&&` instead of `std::initializer_list<int>`? A `std::vector` can't be assigned to a `std::initializer_list` (why is overload resolution even considering that?).  But since the `getRandomN` object can be converted to a temporary `std::vector<int>`, that satisfies both `operator=(std::vector<int> const &)` and `operator=(std::vector<int>&&)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's not assigning a `std::vector` to a `std::initializer_list`, it's assigning a `std::initializer_list` to a `std::vector`.  That is, both `static_cast<std::vector<int>>(getRandomN(10))` and `static_cast<std::initializer_list<int>>(getRandomN(10))` work here and neither is clearly better than the other.

Comment: "*It's not assigning a `std::vector` to a `std::initializer_list`*" - it would be, if it's considering `std::vector::operator=(std::initializer_list)` as a candidate. "*it's assigning a `std::initializer_list` to a `std::vector`*" - and where exactly is that `std::initializer_list` coming from? And I don't see how `static_cast<std::initializer_list<int>>(getRandomN(10))` could work, since `std::initializer` doesn't have an `insert()` method for `getRandomN::operator Container()` to call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `getRandom` produces an object that has an `operator auto()` (for abbreviated syntax) defined.  That means it will match all of the assignment operators that take only a single parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The compiler has already made its overload resolution decision by the time it would look at the body of the conversion operator to find out it's invalid for `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: Nathan, Miles, thanks, I just realized that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that, from the conversion operator's signature alone, the compiler can't tell if it should convert `getRandomN(10)` to a `std::initializer_list<int>` and then assign that to `random_v` or convert `getRandomN(10)` to a `std::vector<int>` and then assign that to `random_v`.  Both involve exactly one user-defined conversion, and so neither is a better choice from the compiler's point of view.

Of course, once you look at the body of the conversion operator it becomes clear that `std::initializer_list<int>` won't work, since it has no `insert` member function, but that's too late.  The compiler makes its choice for overload resolution before looking at the body of the function.

The way to make this work is to make it clear that `std::initializer_list<int>` isn't the right choice from the signature alone.  If you have access to C++20 concepts that's pretty easy:

```
template <typename T>
concept BackInsertable = requires(T t) { t.insert(std::end(t), 0); };

class getRandomN 
{
  size_t count;

public:
  getRandomN(int n = 1) : count(n) {}

  // ------ vvvvvvvvvvvvvv ------ NOTE HERE
  template <BackInsertable Container>
  operator Container () {
    Container c;
    for(size_t i = 0;i < count; ++i)
      c.insert(c.end(), rand()); // push_back is not supported by all standard containers.
    return c;
  }
};
```

Without concepts you'll need to use other SFINAE tricks to make that operator invalid.  Here's one possible implementation that works all the way back to C++11:

```
template <typename T>
using BackInsertable = decltype(std::declval<T&>().insert(std::end(std::declval<T&>()), 0));

class getRandomN 
{
  size_t count;

public:
  getRandomN(int n = 1) : count(n) {}

  template <typename Container, BackInsertable<Container>* = nullptr>
  operator Container () {
    Container c;
    for(size_t i = 0;i < count; ++i)
      c.insert(c.end(), rand()); // push_back is not supported by all standard containers.
    return c;
  }
};
```